# Shortcut to Move Tabs in Firefox

Tags: firefox, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I'm wondering how to move the focused tab around, to right or left, using a keyboard shortcut in 12.04?

After a Google search I found the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + (L/R)Arrows, but it seems to work only in Windows, not in Ubuntu.

Any ideas?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/452298/reorder-rearrange-tabs-using-keyboard-shortcut; the accepted answer works for me on Ubuntu.

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Keyboard+shortcuts#w_windows-tabs

Answer (score 21):

Firefox 19 added shortcuts to move tabs:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> to move left, and
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> to move right.

The change is recorded as [bug #364845](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=364845); here is [the specific commit that added the shortcuts](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/0d16a92e1a41).

Therefore, the [Move Tabs extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/move-tabs/) is no longer required; in fact, if you have it installed you should disable it ([or else the shortcut will move the tab twice](https://github.com/jreybert/move-tabs/issues/2)).

However, there is still no built-in shortcut to move the current tab to the start or end. If you need those shortcuts, keep the extension and in its preferences set the left/right shortcuts to something you don't use.

Answer (score 4):

> Define your own shortcuts to move the tabs into Firefox.  You can move
>   the tabs along the tab bar and at both ends.<sup>1</sup>

That can be done with an add-on, that allows you to define your own shortcuts to move the tabs into Firefox.  Click on the link, to install this [Add-On](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/move-tabs/).  Once installed, restart Firefox, go into add-on, and click on Preferences, to set the shortcuts.  Close the window, and you're set.

[image]

Notice that the **Move** tab is the last one, and in the second image it moved to the first tab.

[image]

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Mozilla Add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/move-tabs/)</sup>

Comment: This is not to move tabs, but to change the current tab. I wanna know how to move. For example: the current tab is the 4th, and I want it to be the 3rd. The only possible way I can do is moving with the mouse, and I was wondering if there is a shortcut for that.

Comment: @Alexandre have tried it and it works.

Comment: That “Move Tabs” extension is gone. The [Move Tab Hotkeys](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/move-tab-hotkeys/) extension works for me (Firefox 82).

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-utilities/) extension for Firefox claims to move the focused tab forwards and backwards, respectively, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>.

Moving the focused tab to the start or end, respectively, can be done with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>

[Mozilla Support](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_windows-tabs) says that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> moves the focused tab left and similarly for right. This, however, did not work for me (Firefox 14.0.1, Ubuntu 12.04LTS).

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox 35 I can cycle through tabs by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>pgup</kbd>/<kbd>pgdown</kbd> move the tab which is kinda cool for organization.

Comment: I confirmed that this works on Mac OS El Capitan with Firefox 53.0

Comment: Specifcally, on a Mac it's:  Fn + up/down arrow + ctrl + shift to **move** a tab. (fn + up/down arrow gets you the "page up" or "page down").

Answer (score 1):

Firefox on Dell XPS 15, Ubuntu 18: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

According to the [relevant part](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Keyboard+shortcuts#w_windows-tabs) of Mozilla's official list of keyboard shortcuts:

```
Move tab in focus left:     Ctrl + Shift + PgUp
Move tab in focus right:    Ctrl + Shift + PgDn     
Move tab in focus to start: Ctrl + Home     
Move tab in focus to end:   Ctrl + End
```